# Solving a diffusion equation in polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nu \left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}+\frac1r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}-\frac{u}{r^2}\right)$$

for the function $u=u(r,t)$. Suppose that

$$u=\Omega r, \text{ when } r\le a,\, t=0.$$
$$u=0 \text{ at } r=a, \, t>0.$$

---

The solution given in the book I am using is

$$u(r,t) = -2\Omega a\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{J_1(\lambda_n r/a)}{\lambda_n J_0(\lambda_n)}\exp{\left(-\lambda_n^2\frac{\nu t}{a^2}\right)}$$

where $\lambda_n$ denotes the positive values of $\lambda$ at which $J_1(\lambda)=0$, and $J_k$ denotes the bessel function of order $k$. Now I'm trying to work out how this solution has been found. Here is my attempt:

---

Suppose $u(r,t) = R(r)T(t)$ then

$$RT' = \nu\left(R''T + \frac1r R'T - \frac{RT}{r^2}\right)$$

Dividing by $RT\nu$ we find

$$\frac{T'}{\nu T} = \frac{R''}R + \frac{R'}{rR} - \frac{1}{r^2} = k = const.$$

So we have separated the problem into two ODE's, namely

$$T'-k\nu T = 0\tag{1}$$
$$r^2R''+rR'-(1+kr^2)R = 0\tag{2}$$

Now here is where I start having troubles. So for $(1)$ we have

$$T(t) = Ae^{k\nu t}$$

but for $(2)$ I can't really find a solution using Bessels function as they have found because the form I require is:

$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} + (x^2-n^2)y=0$$ which I clearly don't have. Also, where has the $\lambda_n$ come from?

Comment: Are you sure there is no $r^2$ in the exponential? To me this looks like a modification of the standard isotropic 2D heat equation, whose fundamental solution is a 2D Gaussian with a growing variance.

Comment: Anyway, you should start by changing variables so that $u^2=kr^2$. After carrying out the chain rule steps you get $u^2 R''+u R'-(1+u^2) R=0$. (Note that nothing really changed in the first two terms.) Now the trick is to change variables to $v=iu$, because your sign in the $R$ term is wrong relative to the ordinary Bessel equation. (This assumes your last ODE for $R$ is correct, which I'm not sure about.)

Comment: As for the $\lambda_n$, these fall out of the boundary conditions. You can think of your Bessel functions as being analogous to sinusoids; to satisfy the boundary condition you need to choose the "frequencies" that vanish at $r=a$ in accordance with your boundary condition.

Comment: @Ian Nope the exponential doesn't include an $r^2$ in the solution. Ok, how did you think of these substitutions? So we get an answer $R(w) = J_1(w)$, how do we get the solution $R(r)$? I have tried this: $$R(w) = R(irk^{1/2}) = J_1(irk^{1/2})$$ however I'm not sure how to simplify the argument of $R$.

Comment: The first substitution turns the $kr^2$ into just $u^2$ without changing anything else; it doesn't change anything else essentially because the first two terms have no units aligned with the units of the independent variable (the $x^2$ units cancel the $dx^2$ units and similar in the $dy/dx$ term). The second substitution again has no effect on the first two terms for the same reason but it switches the sign on the independent variable in the third term, from $-$ as you have it to $+$ as it appears in the Bessel equation.

Comment: So if your steps up to writing down the R ODE are correct, then solutions to the R ODE which vanish at $a$ and do not blow up at $0$ are given by $J_1(i \lambda_n r)$. This is perhaps more conveniently referred to as a modified Bessel function of the first kind, namely $i I_1(\lambda_n r)$. (However, I do not see why $\lambda_n$ should even be real, so I am not sure your previous work is correct.)

Comment: @Ian Aren't the $\lambda_{n}$ guaranteed to be real by Sturm-Liouville theory? As we require $T$ to be bounded, taking the separation constant $k$ to be negative (i.e $k = -\lambda^{2}$) gets us the ODE in $R$ $$r^{2} R'' + r R' + (\lambda^{2} r^{2} - 1) R = 0$$ This, using your transformation, becomes the Bessel ODE with $n = 1$, which is a regular SL problem. Hence the eigenvalues must be real. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I really meant the $\lambda_n$ that appear in the formula that was stated at the top. But you have now pointed out my error: I implicitly assumed to myself that $k$ would be positive, which is why I needed the $v=iu$ solution at all. Assuming it to be negative means the appropriate ODE for $R$ already has a positive coefficient on $r^2 R$ so that you only need to rescale in real variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your ODEs for $T$ and $R$. You want the solution for $T$ to be bounded going forward in time, which requires $k<0$ (since $\nu$ is already given to be positive). To remind ourselves of that, let us write $k=-\lambda^2$, which converts the $R$ ODE into

$$r^2 R''+r R'+(\lambda^2 r^2-1)R=0.$$

Changing the independent variable to $u=\lambda r$ converts the ODE into

$$u^2 R''+u R'+(u^2-1)R=0$$

where now the differentiations are with respect to $u$. (Crucially here, the dimensions of the first two terms do not involve the dimensions of the independent variable, so rescaling the independent variable does not change those terms.) This is now the Bessel ODE with $n=1$; the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ as described in the question now fall out of the assumption that $R(a)=0$.