# Derivation of a Dubious Solution of a Diffusion Equation in Polar Coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, polar-coordinates

I am investigating diffusion of ink in water. I want to compare some experimental results to a solution $u=u(r,t)$ of polar diffusion equation
$$D\cdot\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t},$$
(assuming isotropy, $\theta$ vanishes) with boundary conditions
$$\begin{aligned}&u(r\le a, t=0)=u_0, \\ &u(r>a, t=0)=0.\end{aligned}$$
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946405/solving-a-diffusion-equation-in-polar-coordinates) post suggests a solution via separation of variables, however I cannot understand how it leads to the following solution, as shown in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230978917_Ink_diffusion_in_water) article:
$$u(r,t)=\frac{u_0}{2Dt}e^{\frac{-r^2}{4Dt}}\int_0^a{e^{\frac{-r^2}{4Dt}}I_0\left(\frac{rr'}{2Dt}\right)} r' dr',$$
Where $I_0(z)=J_0(iz)$ is the modiﬁed Bessel function of zeroth order.

Might this be a mistake? The repetition of $e^{\frac{-r^2}{4Dt}}$ inside and outside the integral looks suspicious, but this is the way it appears in the article.
Can someone help to understand the derivation of the solution above, or give an easier to calculate solution?
Much appreciated.

[Side note: If anyone is, by chance, familiar with a Matlab tool to solve this equation numerically (some parabolic equation solver perhaps - or, is solvepde helpful here?) it will be extremely helpful.]

Comment: Matlab's [solvepde](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pde.pdemodel.solvepde.html) might help.

Comment: This most likely is a result of deriving the Green's function for this PDE. Try taking the Fourier transform of both sides w.r.t. $r$ only and solve that PDE.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, changed, thank you.

Comment: Indeed, the Gaussian inside the integral may wish to be in *r'*. You could take all derivatives of the solution and utilize the trivial properties of $I_0$.